# MinGW compiler not working in sublime and vscode

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code, sublimetext3, mingw

So I ran the most basic c and cpp code you can run both in sublime text and vs code. And I keep getting the same problem when compiling.

The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
    printf("hello");

    return 0;


    }
```

The error message: 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file test.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Where is it trying to write test.exe?
Does that path exist?
If yes, is there already a test.exe and do you have permissions to overwrite it or is the file in use, for example because it is already running (check Task Manager / Details)

Comment: Everything was right. I found out Norton was blocking my programs.